# ido-mode and TAB key not working as expected in 24.0.x0 builds

Tags: emacs

```
[Tab] - display possible completion in a buffer (or open the file or go down the directory if there is only one possible completion).
```

This piece of writing came from the [emacs wiki on ido mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/InteractivelyDoThings#toc2).

In my emacs 24.0.50 nightly build from May 5th, on OSX the functionality I had was that when pressing TAB it used to cycle through my choices. Now, if i hit tab, and there is more then one file matching, it pulls up a buffer with the choices.

This is annoying and basically, i want my old tab complete (ala bash) style back.

Anyone know how to fix this? I can map the tab key, but to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `TAB` is doing what it supposed to do. However I use `SPC` to select the next match. 
you can customize the following to use `TAB` instead.

```
;;; additional keys (copied from source file)
(defun ido-my-keys ()
  "Add my keybindings for ido."
  (define-key ido-completion-map " " 'ido-next-match))  ; use space for next match
```

Comment: `SPC` has the same behaviour as `TAB` for me. `SPC` brings up a buffer  instead of just cycling through in the minibuffer. Before and After,  when i added that code too.  Does your `SPC` cycle or bring up a buffer?

Comment: To close the loop on what happened to me, it was another el file and it's coding that actually was messing up ido mode.  `textmate.el` to be exact, so since i didn't need much of that file i just deleted it. If you are getting weird functionality, try looking at some of the other modes and updating them (or deleting). Not everything plays nice together.

Answer (score 6):

In ido customize group ( `M-x customize-group RET ido RET` ) look for " Ido Cannot Complete Command" option and change it from 'ido-completion-help' to 'ido-next-match'

Comment: This worked for me for Emacs 24.5.1 on OS X, while the accepted answer didn't.